# android disadvantages of not closing cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have some questions regarding `Cursor`.

I want to know what are the disadvantages of not closing a `Cursor`?

It deallocates resources, but what resources are deallocated?

If we do not close the `Cursor`? What will be the consequences and to what extent?

Not closing a `Cursor` does not affect `Activity` a bit, but it gives error in a log cat.

Answer (score 8):

Closing a `Cursor` will avoid any potential memory leaks, so **YES** they should always be closed when no longer used.

Comment: isnt java handles all memory issues itself? what special resources in this case? I know It should be close, I just wanna know why?

Comment: A `Cursor` has native resources behind it such as a file handle (remember, a SQLite database uses indexed files). Also, as a side note, `Cursor`s should be closed in a `finally` block to guarantee they get closed.

Comment: which native resources? and how they are so harmful? or do not cause extreme damage?

Comment: Like I said. file handles for example, which need to be closed in order to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll see many issues from forgetting to close one cursor. The issue (and this applies to almost any memory leak) is that if you keep doing it over and over again, eventually something bad will happen.

For example, I wrote an app that uploads data from a device's SQLite DB to a server. If I didn't close the cursor each time I was done reading and writing from the database, eventually I would run into out-of-memory errors and various other issues.

Answer (score 3):

Cursor is only an interface. A lot depends on the implementation, what specific class that implements that interface you are using...

In the case of SQLiteCursor, there are quite a few things getting cleaned-up (this is from Froyo):

```
@Override
public void close() {
    super.close();
    deactivateCommon();
    mQuery.close();
    mDriver.cursorClosed();
}
```

Not closing your Cursor, the data should still be consistent, but you are going to leak memory...

Answer (score -2):

If you do not close the cursor then you will have issues accessing your data in your database because while the database is open, it is not accessible should something happen like the Activity is paused or otherwise. Specifically, this problem can be alleviated if you let the Activity manage it.

Comment: I havnt closed the cursor in my code, and it is displaying data properly,I am accessing data and app is running ok,
it is only giving error in logcat that Finalizing a cursor has not been deactivated or close

Comment: Is your Activity controlling the cursor meaning did you use manageCursor(X) ?