# What is the significance of closing the cursor in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

While reading the sqlite methods to read a row using a `cursor` I get to know about that after retrieving the data form the cursor we should close the cursor to avoid any memory leak, but here I have a doubt that in the code below `cursor.getCount()` is called after closing the cursor? Isn't it wrong to retrieve the data after closing the cursor?
Could anyone can clear this doubt!
Thanks in advance!!

```
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look right to me, but in any case why don't you just make the `getCount` call before closing the cursor?

Comment: I read the code from a reputed site , so I think that it should be correct?

Comment: I can't believe that we need to close the cursor to get the row count.  What is this reputed site?  All the examples I see on SO get the row count before closing the cursor.

Comment: Why dont you close the cursor after getting the count?

Comment: @breakline closing the cursor after getting count is not a problem but I am asking that why it is correct to get the count after closing the cursor?

Comment: If you use `try`/`finally`, you can close the cursor after the `return`. Anyway, to count rows, you should use [queryNumEntries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String)) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the source code for [`SQLiteCursor#close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java#SQLiteCursor.close%28%29):

```
 @Override
 public void close() {
     super.close();
     synchronized (this) {
         mQuery.close();
         mDriver.cursorClosed();
     }
 }
```

And here is the source code for [`SQLiteCursor#getCount()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java#SQLiteCursor.getCount%28%29):

```
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      if (mCount == NO_COUNT) {
          fillWindow(0);
      }
      return mCount;
}
```

As you can see, the row count appears to be stored in a variable `mCount`, and this value is not reset when the cursor is closed.  This might make sense from an efficiency point of view, since it saves the need to clear out state unnecessarily.

So it appears that getting the count after closing the cursor does work, but you probably should not rely upon it because the Javadoc makes no such guarantees, and this behavior could change later on.

Comment: Great explanation!I understood it . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Cursor.getCount()**

here in your query i think the code is not wrong because the getcount() method just return the number of rows in the cursor and we are not retrieving any data from the cursor

Comment: I think that this should be the reason , but I am not understanding that then what types of memory leaks closing the cursor prevents?

Comment: Close() method Closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources and making it completely invalid .[This Article](https://sdgsystems.com/blog/android-memory-and-file-descriptor-leaks-diagnosis-and-debugging-sdg-blog) seems to cover resource leaks well enough. The behavior is inconsistent and it's not always noticeable but [some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892159/android-disadvantages-of-not-closing-cursor/11893092#11893092) have already talked about some of the side effects.