# Why we need to do cursor.close() when we finish use cursor in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, memory, memory-leaks, cursor

I read it online and all I can found that if I don't close cursor, this will make memory leak. But why? 
What reason lead to memory leak?

Comment: Try doing "anayze -> inspect code -> Your file" or look at the little yellow tick marks on the right hand side of the file editor. Android Studio now warns you when forgetting to close a cursor. Also, It is best to close them in the 'finally' clause of a 'try' to prevent them being left open by an exception.

Comment: You can mark it as the correct answer if i answered your question

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, let's say you are drinking several bottles of soda. You are the phone, the soda is the database. Each time you finish one drink, you have to place down the bottle and take the next one otherwise you will end up spilling or dropping some. Of course you can manage drinking the first two or three sodas without placing the bottles down but once you exceed what you can handle, there will be a mess.

This is the same case, you can ignore `cursor.close()` but there will come a point where the phones memory won't handle the number of open SQL database.

Here is also another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892159/android-disadvantages-of-not-closing-cursor/11893092#11893092)